# Extract digit from noisy image

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-tesseract

Extract digit from noisy image

I want to extract text from an image taken by mobile phone camera.
First I try to convert the image to greyscale  by using this code:

```
imgg = Image.open('originale.jpg').convert('LA')
```

Second i try to threshold the grey image to get image with only black and white with this code ::

```
 retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(grayscaled, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite("threshold.png", threshold)
```

Third i try to extract text with pytesseract but i have not the correct result with this code.

```
result5 = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("threshold.png"))
```

This is the image which I want to extract digits number for example:
My expected output is: `111 2 11 4 1 23 2 3`.

and this is my image :

[originale.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Hx9.jpg)

[threshold.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRknM.png)

And this is my full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
img = cv2.imread('originale.jpg')
grayscaled = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(grayscaled, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite("threshold.png", threshold)
result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("threshold.png"))
print(result)
```

Comment: I suggest that you convert the image to grayscale and threshold it so that you have black numbers on white background. Then try to extract the digits as text.

Comment: i try to covert my image to grayscale like this `imgg = Image.open('6.jpg').convert('LA')
imgg.save('greyscale.png')`  then i try to threshold the image `retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(imgg, 49, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Otsu method to determine optimal threshold value to exact your digits.

```
import cv2

img # this is your original image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite("threshold.png", threshold)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: i try this code but i have nothing:  `import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread('3.jpg')


grayscaled = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval, threshold = cv2.threshold(grayscaled, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite("threshold.png", threshold)

result6 = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("threshold.png"))
print(result6)`